# Android : How to determine if soft keyboard type was changed by user while typing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

[image]

I want to get keyevent for change keyboard type by user.

 Requirement is such that I want to adapt text change listener as per keyboard type.